# How to remove entry title container from Genesis child theme

Tags: wordpress, genesis

How to remove entry title container from Genesis child theme ? i can remove title only by the below code for the total site but I can't remove container which occupy some extra spaces.
remove_action('genesis_post_title', 'genesis_do_post_title');

May be by css we can do that but I need if there any Hooks exist.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42779807/4643292) which uses the following code:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_close', 15 );
```

You can use the code in a template file or conditionally in functions.